# Check recursively if dir contains files and exit earlier

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to check recursively if dir contain files using [walker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walker) module.

The issue is that I can't exit earlier once first file found without scanning all directory tree. Scanning all directory tree is time consuming on large file-sets (100,000 files or so), so I want to exit function as soon as possible once first file found.

I'm fine with any `async/await` solution if the module can't handle this properly

Check out the code below:

```js
function dir_contains_files(dir) {

    let files = 0
    const walker = require('walker')

    return walker(dir)

    .on('file', (file, stats) => {
        files++
        console.log(files)
        return files
    })

    .on('error', (err, entry) => {
        console.warn(err, entry)
    })

    .on('end', function() {
       console.log(files)
    })
}
```

Comment: What if you promisify the 'dir_contains_files`, that way you should be able to resolve the promise in the on('file') callback, or reject it on error.

alternatively you can probably emit the end event when it finds a file.

Answer (score 1):

since `require('walker')(dir)` under the hood is `EventEmitter` you can use `once` instead of `on` in your event listeners. Here is working example:

```js
function dir_contains_files(dir) {

    let files = 0
    const walker = require('walker')

    return walker(dir)

    .once('file', (file, stats) => {
        files++
        console.log(files)
        return files
    })

    .on('error', (err, entry) => {
        console.warn(err, entry)
    })

    .on('end', function() {
       console.log(files)
    })
}
```

Or if you need bash script you to return only n first string try this native bash approach

```js
function dir_contains_files(dir) {
    let files = 0
    const child = require('child_process').exec

    return child(`ls -la -r ${dir} | head -n2`).stdout
        .on('data', (file, stats) => {
            console.log(file.toString());
            return files
        })
        .on('error', (err, entry) => {
            console.warn(err, entry)
        })

        .on('end', function() {
            console.log(files)
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yevhenii. I gave it a try. But execution time is the same for `on` and `once` while checking folder with 300,000 files - `once - 6888 ms`, `on - 6693 ms` Are you absolutely sure it stops continue checking folders when first file found?

Comment: oh, if you want get less data from operation system you better use native way and execute proper command with `child_process`. I have added example to my answer, you can take it as a base for your implementation

Comment: Thanks for child process. To my regret I will not be able to use `ls` because searching for multi-platform solution. I'm fine if there is native one with `fs.readdir`